# How to convert Generic List<anonymous type > to Generic List <SubToSubMenu>?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with type convert var to `List<SubToSubMenu>`.
Firstly, I select data from database that is ok !!!!. I received data with `var` variable, but i can't convert `var` type to `List<SubToSubMenu>` data type.

This is my LINQ statement:

```
    var ss =
        db
            .SubToSubMenus
            .Join(
                db.MenuPermissions,
                s => s.ID,
                p => p.SubToSubMenuId,
                (s, p) => new { s, p })
            .Where(w => w.s.Active == true && w.p.RoleId == roleId && w.p.hasPermission == true)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                ID = s.s.ID,
                SubToSubMenuName = s.s.SubToSubMenuName,
                Description = s.s.Description,
            })
            .ToList();
```

This is `SubToSubMenu` class:

```
[Table("SubToSubMenus")]
public class SubToSubMenu : AceEntityBase
{
    public SubToSubMenu()
    { }
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string SubToSubMenuName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SubMenuID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I try it so many way !!! pls show me right direction.

Comment: List<SubToSubMenu> data = ss; Like this !!!

Comment: Post the complete code,you have some major syntax error.

Comment: I think, there is a generic `ToList()` overload. Some kind of `ToList<T>()` or `List<T>()`

Comment: Just keep in mind that `var` isn't a type. It's a keyword telling the compiler to infer the real type.

Answer (score 2):

`var` is not a type, it's syntactic sugar. You have an anonymous type that has no relation whatsoever to your `SubToSubMenu` type.

Instead of projecting into an anonymous type:

```
.Select(s => new { ... })
```

Project into the type you want:

```
.Select(s => new SubToSubMenu { ... })
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to project here. You're already selecting the `SubToSubMenu` from the database, so there should be no need to 'recreate' the class later in the expression chain.

```
var ss =
    db
        .SubToSubMenus
        .Join(
            db.MenuPermissions,
            s => s.ID,
            p => p.SubToSubMenuId,
            (s, p) => new { s, p })
        .Where(w => w.s.Active == true && w.p.RoleId == roleId && w.p.hasPermission == true)
```

This is good so far. You've joined two tables and applied the correct filters.

```
        .Select(s => new
        {
            ID = s.s.ID,
            SubToSubMenuName = s.s.SubToSubMenuName,
            Description = s.s.Description,
        })
        .ToList();
```

OK stop here. If the ultimate goal of this query is to select only `SubToSubMenu` entities, you can replace this part with just

```
.Select(s => s.s);
```

...and ignore the rest of the subsequent statements.

However, you could also go one step further and make the association between the `SubToSubMenu` and `MenuPermissions` entities implicit in your EF configuration, so you'll have no need to .Join in LINQ. Given this, the eventual query should be similar to:

```
var ss = db.SubToSubMenus
    .Where(stsm => stsm.Active
        && stsm.MenuPermissions.RoleId == roleId 
        && stsm.MenuPermissions.HasPermission);
```

Comment: Thumbs up. I was going to give the same answer and saw yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var ss =
        db
            .SubToSubMenus
            .Join(
                db.MenuPermissions,
                s => s.ID,
                p => p.SubToSubMenuId,
                (s, p) => new { s, p })
            .Where(w => w.s.Active == true && w.p.RoleId == roleId && w.p.hasPermission == true)
            .Select(s => new
            {
                ID = s.s.ID,
                SubToSubMenuName = s.s.SubToSubMenuName,
                Description = s.s.Description,
            })
            .ToList()
            .Select(s => new SubToSubMenu()
            {
                ID = s.ID,
                SubToSubMenuName = s.SubToSubMenuName,
                Description = s.Description,
            })
            .ToList();
```

I have added a simple projection to the end of your query. This is to keep the code as close to how you had it to begin with and to aid with any future refactoring.

In this case, it can certainly be coded as a single projection.

Comment: "Try this" is not an answer and there's no need to project twice.

Comment: Why first select into an anonymous type and afterwards in a concrete one?

Comment: I've often found it better for refactoring purposes to keep the database query separate from the in-memory transformations. In this case it doesn't matter, but there are certainly times when we try to run methods or operations that can't be converted to the database. It's a habit that I've gotten in to.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I've edited and explained my reasoning.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - I've explained my reasoning.

Comment: @CodeCaster If I remember well Entity Framework doesn't like when you do projections on mapped classes. So doing `.Select(s => new SubToSubMenu()` in a `IQueryable<>` is "bad". It should be possible to use `.AsEnumerable()` between the two `.Select`, to make the second `.Select` invisible to EF.